# SQL server errors when converting null to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

Have you ever came across this error in SQL Server "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" my query was converting a null value to datetime and throwing that error. To fix it I had to switch from using convert to cast but I want to know why:

If you do the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT ( datetime, NULL, 101 )
```

You get no errors and it returns NULL

but when you use CHAR(0) which is equivalent to NULL

```
SELECT CONVERT ( datetime, CHAR(0), 101 )
```

You get an error, is there a difference between NULL or CHAR(0) ?

Comment: Assertion that char(0) is equivalent to null is false. `select ascii(Null) B, ascii(char(0))`  one is null one is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A character representing `null` and a `null` value are not equivalent.

`select char(0)` does not return `null`, it returns the character with ascii code `0`.